# Joining tables in MySql to store viewed article id's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla site that I am developing and I am a novice when it comes to MySql. I need to be able to track how many articles a user has viewed and then be able to display the total number of viewed articles on the front end of the page (for instance if the user has viewed 3 articles, it should just echo the value '3' to the front end).

I'd also like to be able to store the article id and alias and be able to retrieve that data later if needed. The idea is that any particular user will be able to see how many articles they have viewed and possibly even be able to go back and review those articles (as they will no longer be displayed once viewed).

I haven't the faintest idea of where to start as far as building the table to store this data, and how to join it to the current user. Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it is just pointing me to a good tutorial or resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three approaches, I believe:

**Store All Viewed Article IDs in New Column In User Table**
You could add a column to your user table to store the viewed articles. You could store the article ids as comma-separated values. Each time a new article is viewed you can append a new article ID. On the front-end, you can retrieve this string with a select statement and parse it out to get the individual IDs.

This method may not be practical with a CMS such as Joomla as adding to columns to system tables is asking for trouble.

**New Table With One Row Per User**
You create a new two-column table, one column has the user id and the other has the comma-separated list of viewed articles. There would be a 1-0 relationship between the existing user table and the new table.

A simple join will allow you to retrieve the viewed articles associated with the associated user.

**New Table With One Row Per User/Article Combination**
You create a new two-column history table which stores the user and a single viewed article ID. If a user has viewed ten articles, there will be ten rows.

Retrieving the viewed articles for a given user takes some work as you have to pull in all rows for that user and iterate through them.

**Edit - Sample Code:**

```
<?php
$config['db'] = array (
    'host' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'    => ''
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname='.$config['db']['dbname'],$config['db']['username'],$config['db']['password']);

$query = $db->query("SELECT user_id, article_id FROM viewed_articles WHERE user_id = 1234");

$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>',print_r($rows,true),'</pre>';

?>
```

You would put in your MySQL DB and credentials in the $config array.

Comment: So, if I'm reading option 3 correctly, you're suggesting creating a table 'viewed_articles' for example and having two columns - user_id and article_id, correct? I can easily create the table in phpMyAdmin but I could use some direction as far as the queries are concerned. Let's say I have an article with a 'submit' button. What would the php look like to store the user and article id's in this new table once the article is submitted?

Comment: I've added some sample code as an edit to the answer. Also, you might consider adding an identity column to help with indexing if the table gets large as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I feel like I'm just about there, but I could use some help on the last line of code there. Currently it is echoing a blank array 'Array ( )'. What i'd like to see is the number of rows in the array. In this case, there are no rows since the user has not read any articles. How do I get it to simply display the number '0' instead of the text 'Array ()'? Basically, I want it to count the number of rows in the table and echo the resulting number.

Comment: You can use `echo '<pre>',count($rows),'</pre>';` to get the count.

Comment: You have just made my day. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to use a module to show the data and a plugin to store it.

To track the articles viewed by an user start with the [Joomla documentation for plugin development.](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aPlugin_Development) and look for content plugins.
This plugin should store, at least, the user identifier and the article identifier on a table (call it `articleviews`) created specially for this plugin.

To build a module check the [Joomla module development](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aModule_Development). On this module you will load the data stored with the plugin from the `articleviews` table. Remember to index the table by user identifier, otherwise it will kill your web response as data grows.

EDIT: article identifier should be part of the index too.

Comment: When you say index the table, is this as simple as selecting the 'index' option in phpMyAdmin for the user_id column?

Comment: I don't work often with phpmyadmin and I don't know exactly where it is, but somehwere there should be a link or a button to create an index for a table.